# Gerrit Jenkins Integration

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, gerrit, gerrit-trigger

I have a Jenkins and Gerrit server running in k8s and docker respectively, however I am stuck at trying to integrate both services together.

I've tried following these two manuals.

1. https://www.infoq.com/articles/Gerrit-jenkins-hudson/
2. https://nofluffjuststuff.com/magazine/2016/06/understanding_and_applying_gerrit_part_4_integrating_jenkins_with_gerrit

But they seem well out of date.

Anyone know any good documentation out there to integrate Jenkins and Gerrit?

Comment: I've followed the second doc and it works fine. 
Where are you getting stuck?